How can I handle side effects in NgRx using @ngrx/effects for conditional API calls based on the state?
I'm working on an Angular project where I need to conditionally make API calls based on the current state. I'm using NgRx to manage the state of the application. For example, I have a loadData action that should only trigger an API call if the data isn't already available in the state.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
